# How to add information to Bing Maps WPF Pushpin

Tags: wpf, vb.net, maps, bing-maps, bing

I'm looking to add a custom information tab to each one of my push pins which will appear when clicked or when the cursor glides over it. Being this is a first for me I was wondering how I would go about making a very basic one and because of my current layout of code using VB I would rather use have it in VB instead of XAML.

Currently I'm using a loop to implement multiple pushpins onto the map.

```
Dim CountyLocations(3) As Location
CountyLocations(0) = New Location(55.852663, -2.3889276)
CountyLocations(1) = New Location(55.956023, -3.1607265) 
CountyLocations(2) = New Location(54.840279, -3.2886766) 
CountyLocations(3) = New Location(52.819511, -1.8851815)

For index = 0 to  CountyLocations.Length - 1
Dim Pin = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Pushpin()
Pin.Location =  CountyLocations(index)
UserControl11.BingMap.Children.Add(Pin)
Next
```

Q1. How to create a basic info tab over a pushpin (Resources materials)

Q2. How would I add to my current code?

Comment: Could you specify this a bit more. What do you mean with "info tab"? Do you want something like a tooltab that appears if you hover over a Pushpin? Or do you just want a panel above the Pushpins with some text inside?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I want to make something very basic just a simple rectangle box to appear when the user moves the mouse cursor over the push pin and the text will display the coordinates of that pin, I hope this helps.

Comment: Why don't you use a `ToolTip`? You can put pretty much anything inside a `ToolTip`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes that's what I thought. Just use `ToolTips`. Maybe you have to adapt the `Location`'s string representation to the coordinate format you want. Here is a full working example.

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <wpf:Map x:Name="myMap" ZoomLevel="5" CredentialsProvider="My Key" 
                 Mode="Aerial" Center="55.852663, -2.3889276"></wpf:Map>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
Imports Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF

Class MainWindow

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        CreatePushPinsWithToolTip()
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreatePushPinsWithToolTip()
        Dim CountyLocations(3) As Location
        CountyLocations(0) = New Location(55.852663, -2.3889276)
        CountyLocations(1) = New Location(55.956023, -3.1607265)
        CountyLocations(2) = New Location(54.840279, -3.2886766)
        CountyLocations(3) = New Location(52.819511, -1.8851815)

        For index = 0 To CountyLocations.Length - 1
            Dim Pin = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Pushpin()

            Dim CoordinateTip As ToolTip = New ToolTip()
            CoordinateTip.Content = CountyLocations(index).ToString

            Pin.Location = CountyLocations(index)
            Pin.ToolTip = CoordinateTip
            myMap.Children.Add(Pin)
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Now if you hover the mouse over a `PushPin` the tooltip with the coordinate appears.

[image]

**Edit:**
To display different names just create a collection of `Strings` and use it in the same loop you are creating the `Pushpins` and their `ToolTips`. Here is an example:

```
Private Sub CreatePushPinsWithToolTip()
    Dim CountyLocations(3) As Location
    CountyLocations(0) = New Location(55.852663, -2.3889276)
    CountyLocations(1) = New Location(55.956023, -3.1607265)
    CountyLocations(2) = New Location(54.840279, -3.2886766)
    CountyLocations(3) = New Location(52.819511, -1.8851815)

    Dim names = New String() {"sam", "tom", "leon", "eddy"}

    For index = 0 To CountyLocations.Length - 1
        Dim Pin = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Pushpin()

        Dim CoordinateTip = New ToolTip()
        CoordinateTip.Content = names(index)

        Pin.Location = CountyLocations(index)
        Pin.ToolTip = CoordinateTip
        myMap.Children.Add(Pin)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Brillant Dave thank you very much, in addition if you don't mind do you know how to add lets say text Pin1 over first pin instead of coordinates and Pin2 over the second and so on. Sorry to be pain just curious.

Comment: The `ToolTip` can display what ever you want. In this example you can just change the string. So just change the line `CoordinateTip.Content = CountyLocations(index).ToString` to `CoordinateTip.Content = "Pin" & (index + 1)`.

Comment: Brilliant thanks Dave cant ask for anymore, If you need anything just shout.

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF? The error messages says for the `ToolTip` you are using the "WinForms ToolTip class". This class doesn't have a `Content` property. Even if it's possible, you shouldn't mix WinForms and Wpf Controls. Look at your `Imports` and maybe there is something like `Imports System.Windows.Forms`... Remove that and use `Imports System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip`. Tell me if you still have problems, then I can show you how to use "WinForms ToolTip class".

Comment: Ok I made new project copied the code across on WPF works fine then I'd thought I would do the same on a Windows Forms and still works fine. For some reason when I add it to my project its doesn't like it. Currently I'm working between my map which is on a WPF usercontrol which is displayed on a Windows Form so I decided to put the code on the WinForm. I changed the Imports on my initial project and still have the same outcome. I'm a little confused don't really want to copy everything to a new project just a line.

Comment: Yeah ok. So now I'm a bit confused. However I assume your ToolTip is a Windows Forms control. You can add the text like this: `CoordinateTip.SetToolTip(Pin, ("Pin" & (index + 1)))` . I don't know if this works because in your initial example you have the line `Dim Pin = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Pushpin()` which means your `Pushpin` is a Wpf Control and I don't know if you can add a Windows Forms ToolTip instance to this Control.

Comment: I believe I have found the problem a solution on the other hand might be a little different. Currently after looking closer I can see my application is going between WinForm and UserController just so I can display the map on the same page as the form. What I should really have is the WinForm and WPF.

Comment: I have decided to this this properly no more time wasting I'm going to make it within the Xaml.vb instead of user control. Last I just want to ask is earlier you mentioned about giving each one name e.g. pin1 pin2 by adding one if I wanted to give each other a set name e.g. sam tom etc.. how would I go about it? This is my last question as I believe I'm asking a little too much.

Comment: I added it in my answer under the tag (Edit).

Comment: Thanks Dave for all the help ill try not to bother you again tonight.